# Plotting 3D plots with intersecting planes using `hvplot`

Tags: holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

I was wondering if there’s any way to make [plots like these](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/03d5ae8815b31a7bf26cceba08141f8981e1313dbe644e27e307a74109185433/687474703a2f2f7777772e646172746d6f7574682e6564752f7e72632f636c61737365732f76697369742f74687265655f736c6963652e676966) using `hvplot`.

The reason is that all my data is in NetCDF and I end up using `xarray` a lot for it, so having a way to reproduce those plots (where two structures intersect in 3D space) using `hvplot` directly would be really really handy. I couldn’t find any examples that illustrate that though, or anything in the docs, so I'm not sure it's possible. Is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hvPlot doesn't offer 3D plotting, however HoloViews does. I'd suggest you check the reference gallery of the Matplotlib and Plotly backends to see if the elements you need are available there.